# Raspberry Pi - Python - Check if drive is being written to

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Ok so running raspberry pi (RetroPie) and have a python script running a shutdown, but I want to avoid any possible data corruption when the power button is pressed.

Is there a way to check to see if any of the connected drives are being written to and if so to wait and check again every 2 seconds until it detects nothing else is being written and then continues shutting down.

I am using the retroflag-picase -SafeShutdown.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gpiozero import Button, LED
import os 
from signal import pause

powerPin = 3 
resetPin = 2 
ledPin = 14 
powerenPin = 4 
hold = 1
led = LED(ledPin)
led.on()
power = LED(powerenPin)
power.on()

#functions that handle button events
def when_pressed():
  led.blink(.2,.2)
  # Do check here #
  os.system("sudo killall emulationstation && sleep 5s && sudo shutdown -h now")
def when_released():
  led.on()
def reboot(): 
  os.system("sudo killall emulationstation && sleep 5s && sudo reboot")

btn = Button(powerPin, hold_time=hold)
rebootBtn = Button(resetPin)
rebootBtn.when_pressed = reboot 
btn.when_pressed = when_pressed
btn.when_released = when_released
pause()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`os.sync()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.sync) to wait till everything is written to disk. Or you can use the cmd `sudo sync` instead of `sleep 5s` before reboot